# json_decode with file_get_contents

Tags: php, json

I am trying to use PHP to echo the contents as plain text so that I can use it my application.

I am trying to obtain the contents of http://www.revctrl.com/api/projects/231 which is in jSON format then convert it to an associated array then manually echo the contents in a nice and neat format. But for some reason, file_get_contents is returning NULL everytime.

I have no clue what is wrong with the code.

```
$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.revctrl.com/api/projects/231"), true);
```

The link works in the browser. The jSON output is valid (checked using http://jsonlint.com/).

Any idea why I get a null from file_get_contents?

Is there any server setting that needs to be set to allow outside links to be accessible?

Comment: I've used exactly your code on my localhost and works fine. http://i.imgur.com/IxYopLe.png

Comment: wow.. this is a shock now

Comment: maybe the problem has to do with my host?

Comment: `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);$jsonData = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.revctrl.com/api/projects/231"), true); echo $jsonData;?>` check once.

Comment: I believe the problem is with your **php.ini** file. Can you check if `allow_url_include` is set to `On` in it?

Comment: The upload is failing repeatedly. I don't know why. Sorry for the inconvenience. But I think allow_url_include is enabled. I remember using my own website's domain name in file_get_contents before.

Comment: I think allow_url_include is set to on. I will get back to you once my host fixes the issue.

Comment: Maybe your host ip is banned for multiple requests.

Comment: @prateekkathal Warning: file_get_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure in /home/hidden/www/revctrl.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /home/hidden/www/revctrl.php on line 4

Warning: file_get_contents(https://www.revctrl.com/api/projects/231): failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/hidden/www/revctrl.php on line 4

Comment: When I try to retrieve the above url with file_get_contents it fails to open the stream.  The server returns a 404 http status code.  Isn't that all it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents` just discards the server response body in case the HTTP status code indicates the some kind of error; and standard PHP error reporting won’t give you a much of a clue either in case you’re using the function to make an HTTP request.

You can pass in an HTTP context via [stream_context_create](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php), setting the option `ignore_errors` to `true` – then you will get the error message description the server has likely send in the response body returned.

Use `var_dump` to output it – then you should be able to figure out what goes wrong on the remote end.

Comment: Changing the link from http to https fixed the issue.